# Use django template tag inside {{ verbatim }} and {{endverbatim}}

Tags: django

I have template containing lot of angular tags. So I put `{{ verbatim }}` at top of the html and `{{ endverbatim }}` at bottom of the html.

Now somewhere between template I need to have one check where, I want to use django template's in-built tag.

```
e.g.  

{% if user.group.name == "somename" %}
```

Is it possible to escape that check?

Comment: So, you want to escape the escape, right? I would suggest to either use `{% verbatim %}` on specific angular tags (and from top to bottom) or change the template interpolation of angular from `{{ }}` to something else.

Comment: There are lot of angular tags. 
I do not want to change interpolation for single check in single template.

Comment: It's actually recommended way, to change AngularJS interpolation in Django templates to `{$ ... $}`

Comment: @AndreyShipilov yes, agreed.

Comment: @nik_m : I tried using `{% verbatim %}` separately on each angular tag. It is not working.

Comment: Really you shouldn't be mixing Django and Angular templates at all. Angular templates should just be served as static files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Will it cause any serious issues?

Answer (score 1):

I faced pretty same issue, I created a new tag

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def no_rendering(value):
    return "{{%s}}" % value
```

And use it as follow (mustache template)

```
<h3> {% trans "Question" %} {% no_rendering "j" %} </h3>
```

it will be produce

```
<h3> Question {{j}} </h3>
```

I'm my case using {{verbatim}} will print {% trans "Question" %} as is in the mustache template.